# What are the error codes that mean the socket connection is lost?

Tags: python, sockets, networking, tcp

I have noticed while programming a TCP server in Python that there are some errors that happen in different conditions when one end or the other stops unexpectedly.

For example, sometimes I got "Pipe broken" (`errno.EPIPE`) and sometimes "connection aborted" (`errno.CONNABORTED` or `errno.WSAECONNABORTED`). There's also the thing that across OSs [the codes are not the same](https://stackoverflow.com/q/961465/1043456), but I guess Python's `errno` module handles that.

I searched a lot for a list of the meanings of the error codes of socket connection, without finding what I was looking for.

What I've got until now is something like:

```
try:
    # write or read operation
except socket.error as e:
    if e.errno in (errno.EPIPE, errno.ECONNABORTED, errno.WSAECONNABORTED):
         print 'Connection lost with server...'
```

Until now, everything was working smoothly, and even before adding the last one, I had a problem on Windows, and added it, so I'm afraid there might be some cases I did not handle. Also, sometimes, it just didn't throw an error and kept reading empty lines (with `recv`), and Bad file descriptor, etc.

Does the `SocketServer` class provide such a thing? Or TCP connections in general?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you try to read from a closed socket in python, no Exception is usually raised. You should just read until `recv` returns the emty string.

Writing to a closed socket of course raises an Execption ([`socket.error`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.error)) which wraps the error number that the OS raises.

But you shouldn't concern yourself too much with error codes. Python isn't C, or as the [tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/sockets.html#non-blocking-sockets) puts it when talking about nonblocking sockets:

> You can check return code and error codes and generally drive yourself crazy. If you don’t believe me, try it sometime. Your app will grow large, buggy and suck CPU. So let’s skip the brain-dead solutions and do it right.
>
> ...

Comment: Thank you for the link, as much as I searched I never saw it! I am pretty sure I am getting errors in both cases, but now that I read the tutorial, I think it's because I am using a buffered reader, provided by the `SocketServer` class (`rfile` and `wfile`)... Maybe I'll just use the other method (`recv`, `send`, also available in that class). And yeah I know it would be best to let Python handle the exceptions in the thread, but I guess a traceback does not look good, and that's part of a project, so I'd rather customize the message as much as possible.

Comment: There's a difference between having to check error codes after a function returns normally (in a language without exceptions, such as C) and checking the errno on an exception object that was raised by a function call.  The former is the kind of error prone thing the burden of which languages with exceptions are trying to relieve programmers.  The latter is basically essential to know *what happened*.  In some cases it is enough to know that *something* different from what you wanted to happen happened, but in the majority of cases you actually need to know what did happen.

Comment: Thanks both of you :) I'll just let it fail and ignore it then.

Answer (score 1):

The Python socket module is a mostly thin wrapper around the BSD socket API.  Frequently, you can find documentation for the possible error codes (errno values) by looking at the manual pages for the C BSD socket API.  For example, `man 2 recv`:

```
ERRORS
   These are some standard errors generated by the socket layer.  Additional errors
   may be generated and returned from the underlying protocol modules; see their
   manual pages.

   EAGAIN or EWOULDBLOCK
          The  socket  is  marked  nonblocking  and  the receive operation would
          block, or a receive timeout had been set and the timeout expired before
          data was received.  POSIX.1-2001 allows either error to be returned for
          this case, and does not require these constants to have the same value,
          so a portable application should check for both possibilities.

   EBADF  The argument sockfd is an invalid descriptor.

   ECONNREFUSED
          A remote host refused to allow the network connection (typically because
          it is not running the requested service).

   EFAULT The receive buffer pointer(s) point outside the process's address space.

   EINTR  The receive was interrupted by delivery of a signal before any data were
          available; see signal(7).

   EINVAL Invalid argument passed.

   ENOMEM Could not allocate memory for recvmsg().

   ENOTCONN
          The socket is associated with a connection-oriented protocol and has not
          been connected (see connect(2) and accept(2)).

   ENOTSOCK
          The argument sockfd does not refer to a socket.
```

The manually pages are often incomplete themselves, but they cover more cases than any of the Python documentation.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know where to search for these, as the Python docs seemed incomplete to me. The good approach though seems to be to let the exception be without trying to analyze it further.

Comment: I expect you'll find that to be true until it isn't.